# TranslateY creating conflicts, looking for alternative to push down the content of pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm creating a toolbar which is injected in pages in an IFrame. My problem is to push down the content of the page and create a 45px space at the top for the toolbar.

The code below works fine on some pages, but on other it does create conflicts with some elements like on the widget from codepen on css-tricks.com then some tabs are not clickable anymore after injecting the toolbar.

```
var height = '45px';
var bodyStyle = document.body.style;
var cssTransform = 'transform' in bodyStyle ? 'transform' : 'webkitTransform';
bodyStyle[cssTransform] = 'translateY(' + height + ')';
```

I've tried also to create a class, but this only push down the content on some pages, for example it doesn't work on site like stackoverflow.

Script Injected to create the test class:

```
var html = '<div class="test"></div>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
```

Css:

```
.test {
height: 45px;

}
```

Comment: Why not set the elements position and use the top property

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean something like this, but still it doesn't push the page on some site like stakoverflow or reed.co.uk, the toolbar covers the nav bar of the sites  .test {
    
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
}

Comment: this then works: body, header {
position: relative;
margin-top: 45px;
transition:all 1.0s

}